# Android Camera Intent: What if I want the full size photo but I have no SD Card?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-external-storage

I am working on an Android app which uses the camera intent... I'm working on my Samsung Galaxy S6 which has no SD card. By following the [official documentation tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html), I am able to get the thumbnail version of the photo taken. However, every tutorials I can find to retrieve the full size version includes the use of an external storage (SD card). So my question is : how can I get the full size version of the photo taken when no external storage is available ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an SD card to use getExternalStorage().  Have you actually tried using the code on your Galaxy S6?  If so, what issue exactly have you encountered?

Comment: My bad. I thought that "getExternalStorage()" would mean "having a SD card". I will now test with the official documentation and I should be able to fix everything. Thanks!